# How to send data from Arduino via HC-05?

Tags: android, bluetooth, arduino

I need to send 1 if a button is pressed or 0 if not. So I used this Arduino (Nano) code. When i use it with Serial.println and cheking it on COM port it works:

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
int txPin = 1;
int rxPin =0;
bool y = 1;
bool n = 0;
SoftwareSerial bt(txPin, rxPin);
int btnpin=13;

void setup() {
  pinMode(13, INPUT);
  bt.begin(9600);
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  if(bt.available()) {
    if(digitalRead(btnpin) == HIGH)
      bt.write(y);
    else bt.write(n);
  }
  delay(100);
}
```

I'm trying to check it with Bluetooth Terminal. However I always see this

[image]

[image]

Comment: Besides baudrate problems, characters with ASCII codes 0 and 1 aren't printable characters.

Comment: when i use bt.println("1"); instead of bt.write(y); same problem happens

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, with delay(100); mobile's bluetooth buffer was overfilled, u need to increase delay value to approximately 2000.

Answer (score 2):

Try other baudrates. Some modules have baudrate 38400 as default but some other 9600. Also consider using Serial instead of SoftwareSerial if you have extra UART available.

Comment: i had tried all baudrates, but it did not help me. You mean try to use other pins instead of rx and tx? for example 2 and 3?

Comment: Currently you seem to use pins 0 and 1 which are connected to built-in USB chip. Does it root cause of problems?  You can try SoftwareSerial with other pins or try Serial with pins 0 and 1.